# SKLabelNode text with two different fonts and colour. How is this possible?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I have an `SKLabelNode` which is set up to show the Score Variable followed by the Highscore variable

`scoreLabel.text = "\(score)/\(classicHScoreInt)"`

Now, everything shows fine but i would like the classicHScoreInt to be a smaller font and maybe a different colour. How is this possible?

`classicHScoreInt` is (as stated) an integer and so is `score`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot set two fonts to the same `SKLabelNode` instance. Instead you can write subclasses to create a custom node which contains multiple `SKLabelNodes` with different font sizes. For example, Your scoreLabel can be an instance of the following class.

```
class ScoreLabel : SKNode
{
    var label : SKLabelNode!
    var scoreLabel : SKLabelNode!

    var score : Int = 0 {
        didSet
        {
            scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        }
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
        label = SKLabelNode(text: "Score : ")
        label.position = CGPointMake(0, 0)
        label.fontSize = 20
        addChild(label)

        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "\(0)")
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(label.frame.size.width , 0)
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 25
        addChild(scoreLabel)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

Using `ScoreLabel` class

```
let scoreLabel = ScoreLabel()
scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(100, 300)
scoreLabel.score = 10
self.addChild(scoreLabel)
```

The two labels in `ScoreLabel` acts as a single `SKNode` from the outside.
`SKActions` can be executed on the `ScoreLabel` and it will affect both the `child label nodes`. For instance

```
    scoreLabel.runAction(SKAction.scaleTo(2.0, duration: 2.0))
```

This will scale both labels together as a single unit.

Comment: doesn't the label node support attributed strings?

Comment: does it? I don't think so. I thought this process was easier than generating a string texture from an NSAttributedString manually