# How to create a button on a image in Spritekit/Swift 3?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am creating a game where I created a UI for my main menu screen and I want to apply the play button to show on the play button shown in the image below. I know how to do it via with main.storyboard but don't know how in spritekit. So, when they click on the play button it will go to a different scene which is the (GameScene)

> here is the image.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can approach that in two ways. Either you stick with `SpriteKit` and handle interaction yourself or you mix `SpriteKit` with `UIKit`. In the first case, you would subclass `SKSpriteNode` or create a `SKNode` subclass with a `SKSpriteNode` child

```
SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "...")
```

and handle user interaction by overriding the `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded` functions. Or you go with `UIButton` created with code.

**UPDATE**

Decided to make a quick generic implementation of a `SpriteKit` button. You can try it [here](https://github.com/bajtyngier/SKButtonNode), but keep in mind it was a quick first commit:)

Comment: Is it really safe to mix and match `SpriteKit` and `UIKit` frameworks? Would be nice… ;-)

Comment: It kind of depends on your project. It sometimes causes issues to add `UIKit` elements because they appear on top of `SpriteKit`. But works fine in some cases.

Comment: In the case of a button/gui controls, it's not a big issue to have them on top.  It's actually what you should want.

Comment: @konrad.bajtyngier Nice custom object, I have one very similar that I use as well. Have you considered using a lazy implementation of your TitleLabel? It would clean up your initialization of that object a bit.

Comment: @RonMyschuk good idea, I'll consider in a next commit, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't have a single image for your scene that has the buttons included on it. There is no room for scalability like that. I would create those buttons as a subclass of SKSpriteNode and add them to the scene as objects. That way if you move around the button you don't have to redo your background image. @Konrad.bajtyngier Is on the right path with his implementation, and I use something very similar in all of my games (it becomes an indispensable object that gets copied from game to game). His implementation uses closures () -> () to carry out the actions, there is another option in you can use in your sub class as well.

in your subclass add a delegate

```
protocol ButtonDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func buttonWasPressed(sender: Key)
}

weak var buttonDelegate: ButtonDelegate!
```

and when you create your button just add they scene as the delegate of the button.

```
button.buttonDelegate = self
```

and then in the scene add the buttonWasPressed func. This way you'll will know what button was pressed and handle it accordingly and not have to worry about your objects getting retained by using closures.

I don't feel one method is better than the other, but you should strongly consider sub classing your button, and remove the button backgrounds from your background image.

please see my answer and code here for full details

[Make touch-area for SKLabelNode bigger for small characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42026839/make-touch-area-for-sklabelnode-bigger-for-small-characters/42032549#42032549)